How to implement ElasticSearch in a springboot application?
I am trying to use spring data starter elastic search dependency and i am getting this error which is completely irrelevant.

Dependency :

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>


properties :

spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=http://localhost:9200
spring.elasticsearch.rest.read-timeout=5s
spring.elasticsearch.rest.username=username/ user name
spring.elasticsearch.rest.password=password// password 


config class

 @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient() {
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")).build();
        RestClientTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
        return new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    }
}


model class

@Document(indexName = "products")
public class Product extends BaseModel implements Serializable {


    private String title;
    private Double price;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Category category;

}


Repository class :

package com.Charan.ProductServiceEcom.Repository;

import com.Charan.ProductServiceEcom.Models.Product;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface ProductElasticSearchRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, String> {


}

The issue i am facing :
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-11-25T19:19:16.158+05:30 ERROR 21720 --- [ProductServiceEcom] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearchController' defined in file [C:\Users\Charan\Desktop\personal\ProductServiceEcom\target\classes\com\Charan\ProductServiceEcom\Controllers\ElasticSearchController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productElasticSearchService' defined in file [C:\Users\Charan\Desktop\personal\ProductServiceEcom\target\classes\com\Charan\ProductServiceEcom\Services\ProductElasticSearchService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productElasticSearchRepo' defined in com.Charan.ProductServiceEcom.Repository.ProductElasticSearchRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); No property 'delete' found for type 'Product'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1212) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at com.Charan.ProductServiceEcom.ProductServiceEcomApplication.main(ProductServiceEcomApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productElasticSearchService' defined in file [C:\Users\Charan\Desktop\personal\ProductServiceEcom\target\classes\com\Charan\ProductServiceEcom\Services\ProductElasticSearchService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productElasticSearchRepo' defined in com.Charan.ProductServiceEcom.Repository.ProductElasticSearchRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); No property 'delete' found for type 'Product'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1212) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productElasticSearchRepo' defined in com.Charan.ProductServiceEcom.Repository.ProductElasticSearchRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); No property 'delete' found for type 'Product'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); No property 'delete' found for type 'Product'
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:296) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.delete(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy); No property 'delete' found for type 'Product'
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:124) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:258) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'delete' found for type 'Product'
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:455) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:431) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:344) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:259) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1024) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:260) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:389) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1024) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:390) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5]
    ... 63 common frames omitted

I feel that this error is completely irrelevant and i don't know why the bean is not getting created and throwing irrelevant error suggest something that really works . even blog or a reference video for the implementation will be appreciated

you have problem with your repository, can you upload that code

The problem might be with the version of springboot data elasticsearch and elasticsearch version you are using .check compaitablity matrix

your bean problem is related to missing spring-boot annotations :
@Repository   // add this
public interface ProductElasticSearchRepo extends 
ElasticsearchRepository<Product, String> {
}

also in your entity :
@Document(indexName = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable {
@Id
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.Text)
private String title;

@Field(type = FieldType.Double)
private Double price;

@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
private Category category;

// Getters and setters
}

